# MYSQL query select with multiple Like %

Tags: mysql

In my database I've column type = y, type = x I want to query  WHERE type = "xx" and combine with  Like %

In my query It input all data type y and x even I use where type =  x  how can I display only type Y

```
SELECT * from transfer_money 
WHERE (type = "x") AND ( title LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%') 
      OR ( email LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%') OR ( name_account LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%') 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need the wildcard after `.com`, unless you expect a subdomain in the email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM transfer_money
WHERE (type = "x")
AND (title LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%'
OR email LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%'
OR name_account LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%')
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are in the wrong place:

```
SELECT tm.*
FROM transfer_money tm
WHERE tm.type = 'x' AND
      (tm.title LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%' OR
       tm.email LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%' OR 
       tm.name_account LIKE '%sss@hotmail.com%'
      ) 
ORDER BY tm.created_at DESC ;
```

I should note that if you do not need the wildcards, remove them.